# Publish messages from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#

I have a c# program that launches a python script.  As the script runs, it needs to send text back to the calling c# program to be displayed in a text panel.  I would like to accomplish this with PythonNet.
In my c#, I have this (as a start, but doesn't work):

```
static void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message=" + message);
        }

        static void RunPython()
        {
            string fileName = "";
            fileName = @"C:\Users\xxxxx\source\TestPYScripts\PassArgumentTest.py";
            Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.dll";
            PythonEngine.Initialize();

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
                //parse the path and file name
                string path = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
                sys.path.append(@path);

                // Import the module
                var module = Py.Import(fileNameWithoutExtension);
                using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
                {
                    scope.Set("ShowMessage", new Action<string>(ShowMessage).ToPython());
                    module.InvokeMethod("main");

                }
            }
        }
```

In my python script, I have:

```
def main():
    ShowMessage("Test")

def ShowMessage(msg):
    return msg
```